# javascript date considering Request.UserLanguages[0]

Tags: javascript

How do I format a date in javascript so that displays the date in current browser language format?

I tried so:

```
Date.parse(array[1]);
```

but as far as i looked no parameters for format or language.

Comment: You can use [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Moment.js has robust i18n support. See http://momentjs.com/docs/#/i18n/